# Not an Expert on language switching on click Smarty form needs a hint

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization, smarty

my current code is this but it does not save language onclick

```
<form onsubmit="return false, saveDefaultLanguage('language-picker','default_language');" id="language-picker" action="{$base_url}">
      {foreach from=$set_optional_languages key=k item=v name="local"} <img src="{$base_url}resources/images/flags/{$v}.png" alt="{$v}" width="32" height="32" class="noborder" />
      <input type="radio" id="lang_{$smarty.foreach.local.index}" name="default_language" class="forminput" value="{$v}" {if $smarty.const.LOCAL_LANGUAGE==$v}checked="checked" onclick="saveDefaultLanguage('language-picker','default_language');" {/if} />
      <label for="lang_{$smarty.foreach.local.index}">{$set_installed_languages.$v}</label>
      {if ($smarty.foreach.local.index+1)%5 == 0}
      {/if}
      {/foreach}
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <input type="submit" class="button" name="" value="##DEFAULT_LANG_03##" onsubmit="lang_{$smarty.foreach.local.index};" />
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>
```

My previous working code but in conflict with jquery was

```
<form name="language-picker" id="language-picker" action="{$base_url}" onsubmit="javascript:return false;">
  {foreach from=$set_optional_languages key=k item=v name="local"} <img src="{$base_url}resources/images/flags/{$v}.png" alt="{$v}" width="32" height="32" class="noborder" />
  <input type="radio" id="lang_{$smarty.foreach.local.index}" name="default_language" class="forminput" value="{$v}" {if $smarty.const.LOCAL_LANGUAGE==$v}checked="checked"{/if} onclick="javascript:saveDefaultLanguage('language-picker','default_language');" />
  <label for="lang_{$smarty.foreach.local.index}">{$set_installed_languages.$v}</label>
  {if ($smarty.foreach.local.index+1)%5 == 0}
  {/if}
  {/foreach}
  <input type="button" class="button" name="" value="##DEFAULT_LANG_03##" onclick="javascript:saveDefaultLanguage('language-picker','default_language');" />
</form>
```

Any clue will be appreciated.

Sincerely,

Gvilla.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't save the language `onclick` because you put it inside the smarty `{if}`, probably you want to do something like this instead:

```
{if $smarty.const.LOCAL_LANGUAGE==$v} 
    checked="checked" 
{else}
    onclick="saveDefaultLanguage('language-picker','default_language');" 
{/if}
```

Also, you are using the `onsubmit` attribute in your last `<input>` tag, but this is only valid within a `<form>` tag.

Comment: Thanks Zoltan! I fixed already by using the no conflict JQuery. Cheers!